# How to know where is used sUser_sName() function in my SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm changing the security for a SQL Server 2005 database, so I need to identify every place/ db-object which use the function `sUser_sName()` (SQL function to retrieve the current username connected to the server).

So, is there any way to run a query or something else and retrieve every object which use the function `sUser_sName()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server Management Studio go to your DB->Programmability->Functions->[Your Function Type] then right click on the function then "View Dependencies"

Comment: Does it work with System Functions?, cause I cannot see the option View Dependencies on that function (System Funcs -> Security Funcs)